# Couldn't find story matching - React + Storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook, nextjs-storybook

I am unable to display a story using next.js.
Other stories of the app work fine. This one doesn't. Please I have been banging my head against the wall for 3 hours.

```js
import { ComponentMeta, ComponentStory } from '@storybook/react';
import React from 'react';

import { mockAvailability } from './SpaceAvailability.test';

import SpaceAvailability from './index';

export default {
  title: 'SpaceAvailability',
  component: SpaceAvailability,
} as ComponentMeta<typeof SpaceAvailability>;

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof SpaceAvailability> = (args) => (
  <SpaceAvailability {...args} />
);

export const WeekStartsMonday = Template.bind({});
WeekStartsMonday.args = {
  availability: mockAvailability,
  weekStartsOnMonday: true,
};

export const WeekStartsSunday = Template.bind({});
WeekStartsMonday.args = {
  availability: mockAvailability,
  weekStartsOnMonday: false,
};
```

If I preview the story I get:

[image]

Comment: could you please share your main.js config file and any info related to terminal and console errors?

Comment: For anyone seeing this issue - open your console while storybook is running in the browser (Not VSCode extension).

Answer (score 1):

You have set two times the args of WeekStartsMonday.